# CORS issue with React-Spring Boot Web APP

Tags: java, reactjs, axios

I'm brand new in the world of webdev and I'm trying to develop this very simple app in which you can purchase tickets for football matches. The program worked just fine but I just tried to create a shopping cart, my idea was to push into the database every time that someone adds something to the cart with a property called Paid which will be either 0 (unpaid) or 1 (paid, after checkout).
This was going fine but when I got it all set up, I got to see that the call was being blocked by CORS which is strange because I had everything from CORS set up. This is the pieces of my code that I believe to be relevant:

Controller from my API (every call works except for the getTicketByFanId())

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1/ticket")
public class TicketController {
    @Autowired
    private TicketRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/fan/{id}/{paid}")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Ticket> getTicketByFanId(@PathVariable int id, @PathVariable int paid) {
        return repository.findByFanIDAndPaid(id, paid);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public @ResponseBody String addNewTicket (@RequestBody Ticket ticket) {
        repository.save(ticket);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Ticket> getAllTickets() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

This is what I have set up for WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

I have of course been researching for quite a while and tried most of the things I've seen around several forums (including stackoverflow), but none of the additions seem to fix the issue. I'm almost sure that the issue comes from the fact that I'm taking the variables from the path and so I tried also editing in different ways my configure method which is what's fixing the CORS issues for the rest of the methods.
Among other things, I tried adding code lines like this one:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")
                        .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET")
                        .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
                        .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
                        .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
            }
        };
    }
```

and the biggest result I got was changing the CORS error for a 404 if I just try to allow everying but still nothing fixed...

Regarding my FrontEnd, as mentioned I am using React and I'm making my API calls via AXIOS. This is the call I'm making:

```
(TICKET_API_BASE_URL = http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ticket)
getUnpaidTickets(fanID){
        return axios.get(TICKET_API_BASE_URL + "/" + fanID + "/0");
    }
```

That is being added into an array in the state and then mapped into the site, that's what I have been doing until now and it worked just fine.

This is a screenshot from the error I get every time I try to load the page:

[image: 1]

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ticket/2/0' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ticket/2/0 net::ERR_FAILED

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
```

Thanks in beforehand for anyone who tries to help me!

Comment: What is your TICKET_API_BASE_URL?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ticket

Comment: the 404 is the real error you should look into

Comment: Please edit your question to include formatted text, instead of an image of text, for your error. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Added also the errors as text, also, about the 404, as I said I'm new to webdev but, if I'm not wrong a 404 is a page not found, which is really strange because the page itself loads and if I make a postman request to the same API method with the same data, I do get a response either way... Anyone has any solutions I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you received the `404` error code it indicated that CORS was working properly.

You got the `404` error because you are requesting the following URL with axios:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ticket/2/0
```

But your `@GetMapping` is configured like this:

```
@GetMapping("/fan/{id}/{paid}")
```

Please, note the difference in the **/fan** path.

Either change the axios URL to:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/ticket/fan/2/0
```

Or your controller mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/{paid}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent so many hours trying crazy stuff... Also, I didn't need to do the thing to get the 404 error, apparently CORS is set up just fine.

Comment: You are welcome @Jonacar, I am happy to hear that the answer was helpful. Probably not, although I always prefer to have a global CORS configuration, but with the one you provided for your controller should be enough. Please, do not hesitate to contact me if you need further help.